# Export Oracle query output to HTML

Tags: html, powershell

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("E:\oracle\product\11.2.0\ODP.NET\bin\2.x\Oracle.DataAccess.dll")

$constr = "User Id=system;Password=pass;Data Source=API"
$conn= New-Object Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection($constr)
$conn.Open()
$sql="select name, user_id, password from dba_users"
$command = New-Object Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand($sql,$conn)
$reader=$command.ExecuteReader()
$someArray = @()
#read all rows into a hash table
while ($reader.Read())
{
    $row = @{}
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $reader.FieldCount; $i++)
    {
        $row[$reader.GetName($i)] = $reader.GetValue($i)
    }
    #convert hashtable into an array of PSObjects
    $someArray += New-Object PSObject -Property $row            
}

$conn.Close()
$someArray | Export-Csv C:\temp\someFile.csv
```

This query export result to CSV file.

I want to export it in HTML file. To make it more readable and stylish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For exporting objects to HTML instead of CSV use [`ConvertTo-Html`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849944.aspx) instead of `Export-Csv` and write the output to a file:

```
$style = @"
<style type='text/css'>
th {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
}
</style>
"@

$someArray | ConvertTo-Html -Head $style | Out-File 'C:\temp\someFile.html'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But i am looking for better solution. Like i want to make Row header of table in bold and Red color, values in black color in proper tabular form

Comment: @404 Did you actually bother reading the `ConvertTo-Html` documentation I linked to? The one that explains how to add headers to the generated HTML? Like, `-Head '<style>th {font-weight:bold;color:red;}</style>'` for instance?

Comment: This is how am i doing. add-content $report  "<table width='100%'>" 
Add-Content $report "<tr bgcolor='IndianRed'>" 
Add-Content $report  "<td width='12%' align='center'><B>Server Name</B></td>" 
Add-Content $report "<td width='63%' align='center'><B>Error Code</B></td>" 
Add-Content $report  "<td width='12%' align='center'><B>Date-Time</B></td>" 
Add-Content $report  "<td width='13%' align='center'><b>DB Instance</b></td>". Should i follow the same process.

Comment: @404 If you're asking if you should do all formatting via CSS: yes, you should.